# Sequential and simultaneous price competition

Tags: game-theory, price, industrial-organisation, competition, oligopoly

> Frims 1 (leader) and 2 (follower) compete in price with product differentiation
>
> • Find the equilibrium price, quantity and profit when they choose price simultaneously and sequentially.
>
> - q1=100-10p1+5p2
> - q2=100-10p2+5p1
> - c=0

I have found the best response when they are competing simulataneosly, the price is the same for both firms (6.66), I think it could be correct. But I have difficulty finidng the price and quantity when they are competing sequentialy.

I would be thankful for any suggestions how to calculate it.

Comment: Hi! Can you tell as what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have found the best response when they are competing simultaneously, the price is the same for both firms (6.66), I think it could be correct as the cost and demand are the same. But I have difficulty finding the price and quantity when they are competing sequentially. I think I should start my calculations with the follower and later input the results into the leader but... I don't know how to do it in this exercise.
I would be thankful for any suggestions how to calculate it.

Comment: I recommend reading the chapter of a micro textbook (e.g., Varian) on Stackelberg duopolies, then implementing the same idea.

Comment: I read the textbook and I think the results are ok. Could you confirm? Firstly I calculated best response for firm 1 (leader) as follower will observe and response to the given p1
π1=p1*(100-10p1+5p2)
∂π1/∂p1=100-20p1+5p2=0
P1=1/4p2 + 5
Then I inserted the (p1=1/4p2 + 5) into the best response for firm 2 
∂π2/∂p2=100-20p2+5/4 p2+25=0
results are p2=6 2/3 and p1=6 2/3

Comment: Read textbook again. Best response to $p_1$ should be something like $p_2$ as function of $p_1$. Insertion of $p_2(p_1)$ is not into best response of firm 2. Read textbook again, but more carefully. It is not about the calculations/symbol manupilation, it is about the logic.